# Getting errors while trying to update "vlc" from terminal or snap store

Tags: command-line, video, snap, vlc, apparmor

I am unable to either update or remove "vlc" from terminal or snap store.
I get the following error while trying to run `snap refresh vlc` command from terminal.

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "vlc" (2103) security profiles (cannot setup profiles for snap "vlc": cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.vlc in /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.vlc at line 8: Could not open 'tunables/global'
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: How did you install VLC? From the store?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo snap refresh vlc`?